# Embed Silverlight on Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, silverlight

I was trying to embed a Silverlight application in HTML using Spring and I have problems because the application doesn't show up, but when I use the same code in a simple html (just a folder with Silverlight file + the HTML file) Silverlight works fine, so I want to know if somebody can help me with this.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%"
        type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
        data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," >
    <param name="source" value="/resources/Silverlight/private/SilverlightApplication2.xap"/>
    <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60310.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&amp;v=4.0.60310.0" 
            style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img 
                src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" 
                alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" 
                style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
</object>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in your browser console?  Quite possible that the XAP file was not loaded.  Also, what is the URL of the page on which this object is embedded?  You should also check if you can download the XAP file directly by hitting [http://myserver/resources/Silverlight/private/SilverlightApplication2.xap](http://myserver/resources/Silverlight/private/SilverlightApplication2.xap) because that is what the object source will translate to.

Comment: No I don't have problems in my browser console and I can access to the xap file.